# Why doesn't Compton Shift take place at scattering angle $0^°$ physically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

From the mathematical formula, $$ \Delta \lambda = \dfrac{\mathbf{h}(1 - \cos \phi)}{m\mathtt{c}}$$  that when $\phi = 0$° shifting of wavelength wouldn't take place. But what is the physical reason?

Let there be a stationary electron and **X** - ray is struck on it . What is the physical reason that the wave will not have its wavelength shifted when $\phi = 0^\circ$? Scattering angle is determined when the scattered ray has made that angle after already passing the electron. So, does it mean when the ray does not interact with the particle, the scattering angle becomes zero??

Answer (score 2):

Its actually somehow momentum conservation I think:
By noticing that $\Phi = 0^\circ$ you also can imagine, that the photones momentum did not change, which results in having no interaction and so on the other hand no change of the wavelength.

Comment: That's right, there is no momentum change for photon. The reason for is is just conservation of net momentum in electron-photon system.  But there _is_ interaction, it is **forward scattering** case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll help to think of this as a limiting case.  Compare with a classical case of, say, a BB bouncing off a fixed object.  As the angle of incidence goes to zero, the change in momentum (as N1kon pointed out in his answer) decreases with the sin of the angle ($1-\Phi$ ,to match your equation)  goes to zero as well.  For all practical purposes, the limit is reached when there's no collision, i.e. no interaction.